# WPF Button Style Background Image Swap on IsEnabled

Tags: wpf

We use a custom image for buttons in our project.  We apply this via a style but now have a need to 'disable' the buttons and are trying to swap out the image for a new one.

The first Trigger works 100% as expected.  When the button's IsEnabled == True, the button is 'green'.  When the button's IsEnabled == False, the Green is removed and the Foreground color changes BUT the Grey image will not load up.

Am I missing something???

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="GreenGreyButton">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="..\Images\UI\Buttons\green.png"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFA30046"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="..\Images\UI\Buttons\grey.png"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I have tried both of the suggestions below...
1) The DataTrigger does change the image BUT I am having a hard time getting it into a 'shared style' that can be used on multiple buttons.  Plus I get some syntex errors that do not seem to be valid but at the end of the day it does not work exactly as expected.
2) The default value idea did not work at all - Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pity that when the `IsEnabled` is false, the native style will override all settings (with the default gray background). You can however re-template the button like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="GreenGreyButton">
  <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
             <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                 <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                   Margin="{TempateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
             </Border>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Background">
     <Setter.Value>
         <ImageBrush ImageSource="..\Images\UI\Buttons\green.png"/>
     </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFA30046"/>
  <Style.Triggers> 
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="..\Images\UI\Buttons\grey.png"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: OK This ALMOST works.  It does change the background image but the content of the button (in this case a TextBlock) vanishes and I cannot get it displayed.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @JasonH see my edit, you need more stuff in the `ControlTemplate`. You can even customize it more but it's your part.

Comment: Winnner Winner Chicken Dinner.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Add the image as content to the button & use DatatTrigger instead, like this:

```
<Button...
    >
    <StackPanel>
        <Image>
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="..\Images\UI\Buttons\green.png"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="..\Images\UI\Buttons\grey.png"/>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set default values for your properties

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="GreenGreyButton">
<Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="..\Images\UI\Buttons\green.png"/>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFA30046"/>
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="..\Images\UI\Buttons\grey.png"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```